# Small number of points driving correlation

Tags: r, correlation, outliers

I am currently looking at trying to find high correlations in a series of data. I initially just thought I could check the correlation of the data and choose those with the highest correlation but this is being affected by a small number of points.

[image: Correlation with only 4 points]

The data for this is available in R binary format from [Rdata](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzwZa5mjQb_XelkyQWV6LVVlZ28/edit?usp=sharing)

So when I call `cor(x,y)` I get a value of 0.4187134 yet visually it seems like it should be 0? Also using a linear model produces a significant co-efficient as well?

Unfortunately the correlations I am interested in are quite weak e.g.

[image: Interesting Correlation]

Can anyone suggest a method for giving a high statistic or value to the 2nd figure while producing a low value for the 1st figure?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such case I would recommend to use nonparametric correlation: Spearman or Kendall. Try `cor.test(df$x,df$y,method="spearman")` or `cor.test(df$x,df$y,method="kendall")`.
These coefficients are -0.02 and 0.002 respectively for your data.